# Rename [harvest-moon-anb] → [harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

*[Harvest Moon 3D: A New Beginning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvest_Moon_3D:_A_New_Beginning)* has a tag that was created during the 25-character tag limit. Since we now have a 35-character tag limit, could we please expand it as follows:

- [harvest-moon-anb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvest-moon-anb) → [harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning)

Note that some websites present the game name slightly differently. As described in
[What is the full name of "A New Beginning" in the Harvest Moon series?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/330932/47878), this appears to be the correct name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done :)

[harvest-moon-anb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvest-moon-anb) → [harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning)